# PowerShell - Outputting to a variable not working

Tags: powershell

I am writing a rather lengthy PowerShell script to perform a lot of functions.  For the most part, everything is going very well.

**However,** another function I am running at all levels of the script is a very detailed log. I'll post the command line portion as an example (simplified):

```
    $Batch = $RunMe[1]
    $ResultCode = (Invoke-Expression $Batch -ErrorAction Stop)
    $ResultCode
```

My expected result is:

`Return Code 0`

Then I would log it.  Instead I am getting something like:

`C:\batchfiles\batchfile.bat argument`

Which is the command I am using `Invoke-Expression` to execute.

**Some quick explanation of the variables:**

`$RunMe` is an array that stores the commands (0 is either "Batch" or "Proc" and 1 is the command to run)

`$Batch` is created in the code as written (this is the first reference to it)

`$CurrFileToExec` is the current file being processed (the script runs on a folder at a time).  I'm using it for a string replace for the command line I got from SQL.

I can't get `$ResultCode` to pass the correct output of the command.  It just passes the command line function (`$Batch`) again.

As I said, the actual functionality part works great, but I can't get that return code to my logfile.

Comment: If you could put together a smaller, simpler script illustrating your point with current and expected results I think you'd get better responses. This question is full of implementation details (stuff specific to your job) that makes it hard to understand - i.e. SQL has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: @x0n - Good points, I have pared the question down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I can presume $batch contains external executables, the return code will be in the automatic variable $LASTEXITCODE - invoke-expression's return consists of things written to STDOUT and STDERR by external applications or things written to powershell's output or error streams by script. It will not contain the executable's dos-style return code, if you called one.

Comment: `$Batch` has a batch file and a command line parameter for it.  When I run it manually from a PS prompt, the `$ReturnCode` variable returns the expected output, but not from within the script.

Comment: This is still not working.  Do I need to use a scope with this?  The actual command is in a function in a much larger script.  When I call `$LastExitCode` I just get a blank.

Answer (score 4):

The solution was to modify my `$Batch` variable to add a `cmd /c` to the beginning.  I think there was an issue with just using `Invoke-Expression` and scoping of the output parameter.  I added a line for:

`$Batch = "cmd /c " + $Batch`

Then ran again, and `$ResultCode` had the expected output.